# Woocommerce checkout trigger validation of all fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to trigger validation for the whole checkout form in woocommerce and do something based on having validation errors or not.

Unfortunately I didn't manage to do it.
Anyone has any ideas?

EDIT:
To be more specific, on submitting the woocommerce checkout form. I want to check if all the shipping fields are valid, but prevent submitting the form because I want to process that form data further (but only if it's valid).

Comment: I'm talking about the woocommerce checkout page, which, for people working with woocommerce should be very familiar. I will update anyway.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I'm expecting $('form.checkout').trigger('validate') to do something, but it doesn't. In Chrome devtools, the validation function does not get run. Very confusing.

Comment: Hello, what I did manage to do was to look for all inputs with "validation-required" class, trigger .validate on them, the validation will run and then you can look for inputs with "woocommerce-invalid" class, that will be your indication that something is invalid. Please check if the classes I told you are correct, I'm not sure. If you still don't manage, leave me another content and I'll look through my past code and show you exactly.

Comment: I worked it out thanks - I did something quite similar.

Answer (score 3):

great hints in the comments. Here is the actual working code, to save some time for future people:

```
// Trigger the validation of the fields (you can adjust and pick which fields are validated)    
jQuery('.validate-required input, .validate-required select').trigger('validate');

// Get which fields have failed validation
jQuery('.woocommerce-invalid-required-field').each(function(index, element){
    console.log(element.id)
})
```