# WooCommerce checkout on product page in modal

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, modal-dialog, checkout

Basically I have:
`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_checkout]' ); ?>`
within template file. I retrieve this template via AJAX, and append it to the body, and modal appears with the form. All WooCommerce scripts and styles are enqueued.

If I try to submit the form (to place the order) error validation should be triggered, but this does not happen. It needs to be reinitialized, but I can't figure out how.

I tried with `$( document.body ).trigger( 'init_checkout' );`, but it didn't work, or `$( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );` same thing. 
This is the file: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js

Comment: Hopefully this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47869408/6049581, it doesn't have an answer, but in the comments there's mention of the process that was used to fix it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Frits, I'll look into.